# cdkDropTable error Cannot read property '_getSiblingContainerFromPosition' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular7, mat-table, angular-cdk

I'm using a cdkDropTable that works fine, except the first time I try to drag & drop the elements it doesn't work and the following errors are shown on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_getSiblingContainerFromPosition' of undefined
    at DragRef.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/drag-drop.es5.js.DragRef._updateActiveDropContainer

Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'getItemIndex' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemIndex' of undefined
```

Then if I try to do it again, it works correctly.
In the table I've put:

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource"
cdkDropList
[cdkDropListData]="dataSource.data"
(cdkDropListDropped)="dropTable($event)"
matSort>
```

and in .ts the dropTable method is:

```
dropTable(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    const prevIndex = this.dataSource.data.findIndex((d) => d === event.item.data);
    if(event.previousContainer === event.container){
      moveItemInArray(this.dataSource.data, prevIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, prevIndex, event.currentIndex)
        }
    this.dataSource.data = clonedeep(this.dataSource.data);
    this.tableConfig.tableData = this.dataSource.data;
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
```

I didn't find anything for this, except one answer where a user suggested to add the `detectChanges` method in ngOnInit and ngOnChanges. I've put it but didn't work.

Comment: Did you locate the problem and a possible solution?